# Stop npm restoring entire repository on my ASP NET Core web project

Tags: visual-studio-2015, npm, node-modules, package.json, asp.net-core-1.0

**Question**: After restore, in `ASP NET Core project` > `Dependencies\npm\` a lot of strange packages were included (restored). Packages which does not correspond to my `package.json` configuration file. How to stop it?

In an `Empty ASP.NET Core` Web project which I am going to use as UI project with `angular2` I've added `package.json` file with the **dependencies** and **devDependencies** nodes.

```
{
  "name": "myProject",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "npm run tsc && concurrently \"npm run tsc:w\" \"npm run lite\" ",
    "tsc": "tsc",
    "tsc:w": "tsc -w",
    "lite": "lite-server",
    "typings": "typings",
    "postinstall": "typings install"
  },
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "2.0.0-rc.1",
    "@angular/compiler": "2.0.0-rc.1",
    "@angular/core": "2.0.0-rc.1",
    "@angular/http": "2.0.0-rc.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "2.0.0-rc.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "2.0.0-rc.1",
    "@angular/platform-server": "2.0.0-rc.1",
    "@angular/router": "2.0.0-rc.1",
    "@angular/router-deprecated": "2.0.0-rc.1",
    "@angular/upgrade": "2.0.0-rc.1",
    "es6-shim": "^0.35.1",
    "reflect-metadata": "0.1.3",
    "rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.6",
    "systemjs": "^0.19.27",
    "zone.js": "^0.6.12",
    "bootstrap": "3.3.6",
    "jquery": "2.2.3",
    "font-awesome": "4.6.1",
    "toastr": "2.1.2",
    "chart.js": "2.1.3",
    "signature_pad": "^1.5.3",
    "moment": "2.13.0",
    "fullcalendar": "2.7.1",
    "fullcalendar-scheduler": "1.3.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "concurrently": "^2.0.0",
    "lite-server": "^2.2.0",
    "typescript": "^1.8.10",
    "typings": "^0.8.1",
    "bootstrap": "3.3.6",
    "font-awesome": "4.6.1",
    "toastr": "2.1.2",
    "signature_pad": "^1.5.3"
  }
}
```

Immediately the `Dependencies` folder, from Project structure notified that I must restore `npm` packages.
I opened `npm` folder, I saw there my references from `package.json` and I pressed **[restore]**

[image: restoring Dependencies]

At the end of restore in `npm` folder, under `Dependencies` and I saw **a lot of references was added automatically**.
**node_modules** folder contains 361 packages, instead of mine : 28 packages defined in `package.json`.

I don't know why they were included.
Does anyone know why this happened? How to avoid that redundancy ...

I see it is possible to uninstall packages one by one.... Should I uninstall them from that `npm` folder?

[image: strange packages included]

Thanks.

Comment: What version of ASP.NET Core tools for VS do you have installed? Do you have npm/Node.js installed on the machine, and if so, what version?

Comment: Visual Studio 2015 update 2; npm 3.8.8;  Node 6.1.0; ASP.NET and Web Tools 2015.1; Microsoft .NET Core Tools (Preview 1) 14.1.20512.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer: You shouldn't delete or uninstall the extra packages. They are dependencies of the packages listed in your `package.json`.

Newer versions of npm changed the way package dependencies are installed. Older versions would always install the dependencies of a package under the package's folder, and the dependencies of each of those packages under their folders, and so on. This was good for dependency isolation, but it resulted in deeply nested folder structures that caused problems on Windows because they would exceed `MAX_PATH`. Newer versions of npm install shareable child dependencies in the root folder. You're seeing roughly the same set of packages you got before, just in a flatter folder structure.

Now, prior to the recent ASP.NET Core RC2 release, the Web Tools for VS did not display this new structure very well. All those flattened packages would show up as "extraneous" root packages. If you can upgrade the Web Tools to the RC2 release, then you should see what you expect under the npm node: Only the packages in your `package.json`, with the other packages nested below them.

Comment: Yes Joe, i find out that they are dependencies of my existing packages listed in package.json. A lot of them are the dependencies for `concurrently` and for `lite-server` :) . I played by uninstalling them, but `npm start` command **crashed** :) So, I restored them back. Thanks for explanations! Good job!